# sliding the UIProgressView (animate)

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to to slide a progress bar downwards. when running the code, the bar jumps 11 points downwards and slides to the original. i was expecting it to slide 11 points downwards from it's original position.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
     self.progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.progressBar.frame.origin.x, self.progressBar.frame.origin.y + 11 , self.progressBar.frame.size.width, self.progressBar.frame.size.height);
}];
```

anything wrong?

Comment: Where in the lifecycle of the `UIViewController` are you invoking the animation - e.g., `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, other?

Comment: The code is fine - we'll need more context to say why it doesn't work

Comment: i'm running this code in a custom delegate method that i created.

Answer (score 0):

It's much more intuitive to use `CGRectOffset` for these kinds of animations. Use it, give it your dx and dy values and see if it does what you intended.